# Python: Customize docstring for individual objects of same class?

Tags: python, docstring

in my project, I have lots of instances of the same type of variables, with different purposes. I want to be able to use the python help system to give users info on what every object does. What is the best way to customize the docsting or any other help system on the fly? I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```py
a = myClass()
b = myClass()
a.__doc__ = "this is instance a and does something."
b.__doc__ = "this is instance b. It does something else."

...

>>> help(a)
"this is instance a and does something."
>>> help(b)
"this is instance b. It does something else."
```

However, it appears that changing `__doc__` on an instance of an object doesn't do anything.

Is is possible to do this in python, or will I need to write my own help functions? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like it should be two different classes, or subclasses of the same class. If we take an existing example: `a=str(); b=str()`. Would you expect `a` and `b` to do different things, or to act differently when given the same input?

Comment: Instances should generally only differ by their state. So a and b should do the same thing, only to other targets. If the two are distinctly different, why not turn them into separate classes?

Comment: Unless `myClass` is a function that produces classes (parameterized ones for example) the above comments are a way to go. Split them into separate classes or let them behave identically.

Comment: @G.Anderson Sorry, I wasn't clear. The classes do exactly the same thing, but their usage may differ. for example, they may both be ints that control two different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`__doc__` is mostly only used with functions and class definitions, but if you want to show info about an instance you will need to write a small function for it, or just `print(a.__doc__)`

Answer (score 0):

`__doc__` is only for classes, and not for instances. I think the best thing to do in this situation is to create a attribute unique to each instance and store the docstring there